# How does Destiny 2 save?

Tags: destiny-2

Sorry, I’m new to the game and was wondering how to save the game/know when it autosaves.  This was not explained in the (very limited) tutorial.  I don’t want to lose all my progress so far.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Gear will be saved the moment you acquire it.

Mission progress will be lost if you quit. Most of the time, missions are short enough that it should be considered "acceptable" if you have to quit early. Once a mission is complete and you return to the solar system map, that mission counts as completed.

The intro tutorial is actually a collection of missions, and I'm pretty sure if you quit during one, it will bring you back to the most appropriate starting point.

There are checkpoints in some missions that it reverts to if you die, but these aren't stored after quitting.

Comment: Story missions do have waypoints. If you quit the game or change character in a mission, when you re-start the mission you'll start from the waypoint. On the director an icon will be displayed next to the launch button, telling you about the waypoint with an option to reset to the start of the mission.

Comment: Story missions do start at the last passed checkpoint. You do need to go to the mission departure point each time you start the mission manually though. Please edit accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

Destiny and Destiny 2 are *always online* RPGs and the games will be continuously saved. It would be almost impossible for progress to be lost, and there is no need (and no possible way) to manually save.

Go ahead and play and quit whenever you like and you won't lose experience, gear, or bounty progress. But if you are in the middle of a story mission, patrol mission, strike, raid, crucible/gambit match, ect then that progress will be lost and will need to be redone.

Comment: You might want to make specific mention of mission/raid progress, as covered in the other answer.

Comment: nope, anywhere beyond a checkpoint is lost if the game crashes,you can also lose engrams during decryption if game crashes.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answers, your data is saved to your account while you play. Everything you do is stored on your account's database entries.
A list like this is generated based on the data that is saved on the destiny servers, and your game is loaded based on the values that you've accumulated so far. So your PlayStation/PC will send a query to the destiny servers that hold this information like,
SQLConnectionString = "server:10.10.103.424 userid=admin pass=password"
SQLQuery = "Select * from savedCharacterValueTable"--this table holding queries of it's own that ask the other tables for information(like a bodyArmorTable and a weaponTable). The results are stored on a list. then loaded to your game on startup.

A list like this is easy to load from.
Account #:1232323
Class:Hunter
Items.Weapons = [Gun1, Gun2, etc.]
Items.Head = [Helmet1, Helmet2, etc.]
Items.CurrentlyEquipped(Head=HelmentGreen,Body=ArmorLastLoggedOffWith,MainGun=gun1,SubGun=gun5)
Glimmer = 100000
Total Strikes = 500
Crucible.Control.Total = 200
Crucible.Control.Win = 150
Crucible.Control.Loss = 50